# TargetDeviceFamily not recognized

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xaml, packaging, targets

I have the following code in my `package.appxmanifest`, and I'm getting an error that the `TargetDeviceFamily` is an "unrecognized XML element"...  I don't know what the hell is going on, but it's this document is the last thing from me publishing my app, and I'm losing my mind.  Can't find anything on MSDN and their support wasn't that supportive.

### Code:

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="6.3.0" MaxVersionTested="6.3.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

### Error:

[image]

### Amendment:

When I remove the `Dependancies` and `TargetDeviceFamily`, I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, using Windows.Desktop as a target is not so common.  Only makes sense if you are using the UWP desktop bridge.  A detail that belongs in the question.  At least the version numbers are wrong, they must be Win10 versions.  Do compare the appx manifest with [a sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample/cs/UWP/Package.appxmanifest) to find more possible differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update the min and max versions to

```
MinVersion="10.0.x.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.y.0"
```

Comment: Yup windows 10 ... x and y you can replace with the build of the windows 10. Or if you are using some other windows just replace 10 with whatever major version.
mine is windows 7 so in mycase it shows 6.1.7601.0

Answer (score 2):

Does your `package.appxmanifest` contain the required namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10`?

```
<Package 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10">
  ...
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="6.3.0" MaxVersionTested="6.3.0" />
  </Dependencies>
</Package>
```

Comment: yes it does.  i'll update the question to show the full packaging code.